# SQL ACCESS how to select and then append column wise

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am wondering how I can query select Value for each ID from source table shown below
[image]

and then append column wise to create a table like this
[image]

I only know how to select for one ID like this

```
SELECT DATA1.No,DATA1.Value
FROM DATA1
WHERE DATA1.ID='F'
```

Comment: You need to use a pivot table to achieve that.  Here's one guide to doing it: https://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/complete-information-about-ms-access-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better change value field to val (value is reserved word),
and the  SQL :

```
TRANSFORM Sum(DATA1.Value) AS SumOfValue
SELECT DATA1.[NO]
FROM DATA1
GROUP BY DATA1.[NO]
PIVOT DATA1.ID;
```